# I can't find my PHP issue

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, testing, browser

Please, help me.
Excuse me for my bad English.
I am working on an online test management system with PHP language.
I have a problem.
When I take a test from my users, for some users there is a problem
when they submit the test page and they want to see their result. The insert query doesn't perform correctly and some columns in my table are empty.
I tried to find the problem but I couldn't find it.
I took 1000 test from myself but I can't see any problem.
In modern computers there isn't any problem.
Could it be a browser problem?
Could it be a computer problem?
Please, help me.

my test.php code

http://www.ticktest.ir/test.txt

my result.php code

http://www.ticktest.ir/result.txt

Comment: I can't find your question explanatory - without codes

Comment: without any code and/or details... one can only guess..

Comment: bad english is excusable... no code or details is not.

Comment: Try posting your code. If I had to guess I'd bet that you're not sanitizing your data when you're trying to insert it into a database and some people are submitting values that have apostrophes in them (').

Comment: Definitely need more details - any logs, errors, etc.  Basically you've told us "Sometimes the INSERT fails.  Tell me why."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a browser problem. It could be a code problem. It could be a server problem.

Have you tried using something like Firebug to watch what happens when you yourself take the test? Have you also tried using Firebug Lite - Firebug plugins available for other browsers, which include some-but-not-all Firebug functionality?

In Firefox, launch Firebug and select the Console tab. Then go to your test page, and watch to see if there are any errors or warnings. If there aren't actually take another test yourself and submit it - and watch to see if there are any errors.

If everything works excellently in Firefox, run the same tests in Chrome, Safari, and IE (on Windows and MAC.)

If you've already tried all of those and there is no browser problem, possibly look at some PHP debuggers to see if your PHP script is communicating properly with your database.

If you haven't done any testing yet, troubleshoot the server side (PHP script talking to your database.) If that's working, then try the various different browsers (client side).

Comment: there isn't any errors for me and my friends but some other people have some errors and i cant understand it

Comment: Then you'll need to find someone who can troubleshoot this problem. Try searching in Google for the exact error code, and go from there. Or try posting your code and what steps you've actually taken, like the other posters have suggested. People around here will assist, but they can't assist if you don't give them more to work with. (I myself only know the overall steps to troubleshoot. I can't give you much more help than I already have.) You might try asking these others, who have errors, what errors they're seeing.